# I am getting an unusual url error in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

As you can see below, I have presented the URL below in a completely normal way, but for some reason I get the error that you can too see below.

What can I be doing?

The code:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => '{{ URL::route('try_login') }}', 'class'=>'login_form', 'id'=>'login_reg_form', 'role' => 'form')) }}

        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address', array('class' => 'email')); }}

        {{ Form::text('email', 'example@gmail.com', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password', array('class' => 'password')); }}

        {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

        {{ Form::submit('Click Me!'); }}

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

The error message:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_PARSE) 
syntax error, unexpected 'try_login' (T_STRING), expecting ')'


<?php echo Form::open(array('action' => '{{ URL::route('try_login'); ?>', 'class'=>'login_form', 'id'=>'login_reg_form', 'role' => 'form')) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Form::open()` function is incorrect. It should be

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => URL::route('try_login'), 'class'=>'login_form', 'id'=>'login_reg_form', 'role' => 'form')) }}
```

Comment: It does not seem to be working. I get a route not defined error.

Comment: This is, however, the answer to your question. Now you simply need to define the route in your routes.php file. See Named Routes:  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes

Comment: The routes had already been defined before i wrote the question.

Comment: You'll need to post your route file if you want us to help any further. But I've answered the question that was asked.

Comment: @Tapha has this question been answered? If so - can you please accept it - or provide more info